# Error in model.frame.default ..... : invalid type (list) for variable

Tags: r

I'm new to R and getting the above error when running a neural network with the code below.
It works up until the "neuralnet" step and the following erroris displaye, which I can't resolve and the solutions in other threads don't seem to be the same (full output report including data below):
"Error in model.frame.default(formula.reverse, data) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'TrainingOutput.Y'"

the only thing that I see that is wrong (but haven't a solution for) is that the header for the first column is preceeded by strange characters even though these are not in the csv file ("ï..")- but I would doubt that this has an effect.
any suggestions?

**Code being used:**

```
install.packages('neuralnet')  # Install neuralnet
library(neuralnet)             # Load neuralnet
#Read Output Data from CSV
TrainingOutput.Y <- read.csv("C:\\data\\OutputData.csv", header = T)
#Read Input Data from CSV
TrainingInput.X <- read.csv("C:\\data\\InputData.csv", header = T)
# Join the columns and coerce to dataframe
head(TrainingInput.X)
head(TrainingOutput.Y)
TrainingSet.XY <- as.data.frame(cbind(TrainingInput.X, TrainingOutput.Y))
head(TrainingSet.XY)
# Train neural network
net.ILB <- neuralnet(TrainingOutput.Y ~ TrainingInput.X, 
                  TrainingSet.XY,
                  hidden = 1, 
                  threshold = 0.0001)
```

**The full output report is:**

```
library(neuralnet)             # Load neuralnet
#Read Output Data from CSV
TrainingOutput.Y <- read.csv("C:\\data\\OutputData.csv", header = T)
#Read Input Data from CSV
TrainingInput.X <- read.csv("C:\\data\\InputData.csv", header = T)
# Join the columns and coerce to dataframe
head(TrainingInput.X)
#   ï..Poot Scharnier Begrenzer Koppeling geleiders totalitems
# 1   0.114     0.036     0.036     0.016     0.016      0.443
# 2   0.025     0.009     0.009     0.008     0.008      0.193
# 3   0.000     0.016     0.016     0.008     0.008      0.123
# 4   0.050     0.017     0.017     0.001     0.001      0.359
# 5   0.070     0.006     0.006     0.004     0.004      0.268
# 6   0.004     0.008     0.008     0.002     0.002      0.061
head(TrainingOutput.Y)
#        ï..Hours
# 1 0.66783333333
# 2 0.20643333333
# 3 0.22733566667
# 4 0.65986666667
# 5 0.16406666667
# 6 0.05576666667
TrainingSet.XY <- as.data.frame(cbind(TrainingInput.X, TrainingOutput.Y))
head(TrainingSet.XY)
#   ï..Poot Scharnier Begrenzer Koppeling geleiders totalitems      ï..Hours
# 1   0.114     0.036     0.036     0.016     0.016      0.443 0.66783333333
# 2   0.025     0.009     0.009     0.008     0.008      0.193 0.20643333333
# 3   0.000     0.016     0.016     0.008     0.008      0.123 0.22733566667
# 4   0.050     0.017     0.017     0.001     0.001      0.359 0.65986666667
# 5   0.070     0.006     0.006     0.004     0.004      0.268 0.16406666667
# 6   0.004     0.008     0.008     0.002     0.002      0.061 0.05576666667
# Train neural network
net.ILB <- neuralnet(TrainingOutput.Y ~ TrainingInput.X, 
                      TrainingSet.XY,
                      hidden = 1, 
                      threshold = 0.0001)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula.reverse, data) : 
>     invalid type (list) for variable 'TrainingOutput.Y'

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be passing data.frames in a formula. Also, you are going to want to look into where those weird characters are coming from in your variable names. That doesn't seem right. (Maybe your CSV has a byte-order-marker? Not sure what the encoding might be.) You can "clean" the names with

```
names(TrainingInput.X)[1]<-"Poot"
names(TrainingOutput.Y)[1]<-"Hours"
```

and then your neural net call should look like this

```
net.ILB <- neuralnet(Hours ~ Poot + Scharnier + Begrenzer + Koppeling + geleiders + totalitems, 
                      TrainingSet.XY,
                      hidden = 1, 
                      threshold = 0.0001)'
```

This formula means we want to model `Hours` based on all the other columns in the `TrainingSet.XY` data.frame.

Comment: thanks for your quick response MrFlick, I made the changes you suggested and indeed got a different error - this time in relation to the "." in the formula:

Comment: Result: > # Train neural network
> net.ILB <- neuralnet(Hours ~ ., 
+                       TrainingSet.XY,
+                       hidden = 1, 
+                       threshold = 0.0001)
Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

Comment: @Coole OK. I updated my answer. For whatever reason that `neuralnet` function doesn't support the `.` syntax like nearly every other modeling function. You need to list all the columns. You could also use `reformulate(names(TrainingInput.X), names(TrainingInput.Y))` to build the formula for you.