# Getting error "invalid type (list) for variable" when running multiple models in a for loop: how to specify outcome/predictors?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, regression, ordinal

For a study I am working on I need to create bootstrapped datasets and inverse probability weights for each dataset and then run a series of models for each of these datasets/weights. I am attempting to do this with a nested for-loop where the first part of the loop creates the weights and the nested loop runs a series of models, each with different outcome variables and/or predictors. I am running about 80 models for each bootstrapped dataset, hence the reason for a more automated way to do this. Below is a example of what I am doing with some mock data:

```
# Creation of mock data

data <- data.frame("Severity" = as.factor(c(rep("None", 25), rep("Mild", 25), rep("Moderate", 25), rep("Severe", 25))), "Severity2" = as.factor(c(rep("None", 40), rep("Mild", 20), rep("Moderate", 20), rep("Severe", 20))), "Weight" = rnorm(100,  mean = 160, sd = 30), "Age" = rnorm(100,  mean = 40, sd = 7), "Gender" = as.factor(rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.5)), "Tested" = as.factor(rbinom(100, size = 1, prob = 0.4)))

data$Severity <- ifelse(data$Tested == 0, NA, data$Severity)
data$Severity2 <- ifelse(data$Tested == 0, NA, data$Severity2)

data$Severity <- ordered(data$Severity, levels = c("None", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"))
data$Severity2 <- ordered(data$Severity2, levels = c("None", "Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"))


# Creating boostrapped datasets
nboot <- 2
set.seed(10)
boot.samples <- lapply(1:nboot, function(i) {
  data[base::sample(1:nrow(data), replace = TRUE),]
})

# Create empty list to store results later
coefs <- list()  

# Setting up the outcomes/predictors of each of the models I will run
mod1 <- list("outcome" <- "Severity", "preds" <- c("Weight","Age"))
mod2 <- list("outcome" <- "Severity2", "preds" <- c("Weight", "Age", "Gender"))
models <- list(mod1, mod2)

# Running the for-loop
for(i in 1:length(boot.samples)) {
  
  #Setting up weight creation
  null <- glm(formula = Tested ~ 1, family = "binomial", data = boot.samples[[i]])
  full <- glm(formula = Tested ~ Age, family = "binomial", data = boot.samples[[i]])
  step <- step(null, k = 2, direction = "forward", scope=list(lower = null, upper = full),  trace = 0)
  pd.combined <- stats::predict(step, type = "response")
  numer.combined <- glm(Tested ~ 1, family = "binomial", 
                        data = boot.samples[[i]])
  pn.combined <- stats::predict(numer.combined, type = "response") 
  
 # Creating stabilized weights
  boot.samples[[i]]$ipw <- ifelse(boot.samples[[i]]$Tested==0, ((1-pn.combined)/(1-pd.combined)), (pn.combined)/(pd.combined))
  
   
  # Now running each model and storing the coefficients

      for(j in 1:length(models)) {   
          
  outcome <- models[[j]][[1]] # Set the outcome name   
  
  predictors <- models[[j]][[2]] # Set the predictor names
  
  model_results <- polr(boot.samples[[i]][,outcome] ~ boot.samples[[i]][, predictors], weights = boot.samples[[i]]$ipw, method = c("logistic"), Hess = TRUE) #Run the model
  
  coefs[[j]] <- model_results$coefficients # Store regression model coefficients in list
  


  }
   
}
```

The portion for creating the IPW weights works just fine, but I keep getting an error for the modeling portion that reads:

"Error in model.frame.default(formula = boot.samples[[i]][, outcome] ~ :
invalid type (list) for variable 'boot.samples[[i]][, predictors]'"

Based on the question asked and answered here: [Error in model.frame.default ..... : invalid type (list) for variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489691/error-in-model-frame-default-invalid-type-list-for-variable) I know that the issue is with how I'm calling the outcomes and predictors in the model. I've messed around lots of different ways to handle this to no avail, I need to specify the outcome and predictors as I do because in my actual models the outcomes and predictors changes with each model! Any ideas on how to deal with this would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried something like setting outcome <- boot.samples[[i]][,outcome] outside of the model and then just calling outcome in the model, but that gives me the same error.